# how can I set form validation?

Tags: php, forms, validation

How can I use PHP form validation with this code? Thank you

```
<?php
$hostname = ""; // usually is localhost, but if not sure, check with your hosting company, if you are with webune leave as localhost
$db_user = ""; // change to your database password
$db_password = ""; // change to your database password
$database = ""; // provide your database name
$db_table = ""; // leave this as is


# STOP HERE
####################################################################
# THIS CODE IS USED TO CONNECT TO THE MYSQL DATABASE
$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add your url to our database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) {
# THIS CODE TELL MYSQL TO INSERT THE DATA FROM THE FORM INTO YOUR MYSQL TABLE
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(title,description,url,keywords) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['title']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['description']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['url']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['keywords']))."')";
if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) {
echo '<h1>Thank you</h1>Your information has been entered into our database<br><br>';
} else {
echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
}
} else {
?>
<h1><center><center></h1>

<hr>

<center>
<form method="post" action="">
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp title:<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="title">
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp description: <br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="description">
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Url: <br>
<font color="#0000FF">http://</font><input type="text" name="url">

<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form></br>
<?php

}
?>  <center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a mess, please highlight and format your codes with the curly brackets {}.

Comment: Hi @mofhd, when entering/editing a question, click on the orange  box with the question mark to see how formatting works

Comment: ok i did it 3 more to go

Comment: I would suggest you not even use it if you didn't make it. Notes are messed up, logics not what it should be, and is a mess of a jumble up and don't even seem like a validating script to me.

Comment: You need to validate your values ($_REQUEST['title'] and such) before running the INSERT query. If value is fine, assign it to a variable (using escape string for sure). If not, add it to errors array. If errors array is empty - run insert query and display some message on success. If there are errors - display them and do not run the INSERT query.  But if you don't even understand the logic, probably don't even get into that. Get some PHP book instead, most of them have good examples of how to handle forms.

Comment: add the rest of the validation in your condition if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && !empty($_POST['url']) && so on)

Comment: I disagree with robx's comment about not using it if you didnt make it. It's very common for programmers to be asked to modify something they didnt make. I admit, i would eventually re-do almost every aspect of it, but it's a better starting point than a blank slate.

Comment: @Good Time Tribe, I'm not saying its bad to use something someone else made, but this one could just use a lot of fix up and could be much more cleaner. IE all those &nbsp is unnecessary, documentation could be made more clear as well on the $db_user, and the If statement is just assigning value, not really checking conditions etc...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the filter_var() and filter_input() functions to filter your input. I also encourage you to use PDO prepared statements to protect against SQL injection. For form validation, you'll  need to compare the value of the inputs to what you are willing to accept. Also, you'll need at least one more condition statement to determine what to do based on whether the input is valid (add it to sql) vs invalid (display error).